# Django Form with java-script misbehaving in IE

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-forms

I have a django form where it has name , address, zip, etc. as well as a pickup dates field for a donation service. I have it setup so that after a user enters in a zip code and leaves the field to send an ajax request to a django view to return all of the pickups that will match that zip code. Everything works fine in chrome, firefox, safari but of course IE is being a royal pain in the you know what. The `$('#results').hide();`below does not seem to work for some users despite having JS enabled and seeing the source code. Somehow is it all breaking?

Errors have been that no pickup dates are being returned in IE and when submitted it's giving a 403 csrf error depsite me having the tag within the form. Below is my JS for the form. Is there anything in here IE specific that would cause a problem? The main function to get the pickup dates is function get_pickup_dates

```
Query(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});

function get_pickup_dates(zip,template)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/get_pickups/",
        data: {
        'zip': zip, 
        'template':template
        },
        success: function(data){            

                date_results = $(data).find('#results').html()          
                $("#id_pickup_date").replaceWith("<span>" + date_results + "</span >");     
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
}


$(document).ready(function()
{   

template = window.location.pathname;
$('#results').hide();
$('#id_cancel').closest('div').hide()

    if (template == '/donate/')
    {
        address_fields = $("#id_address_number, #id_city, #donateForm #id_zip, #externalForm #id_zip, #id_address_street, #id_pickup_id").closest('div');
        $(address_fields).hide();

    }

    if (template == '/external/')
    {
        $("#id_zip").live('focusout',function()
        {
            zip = $(this).val()
            get_pickup_dates(zip,template)
        });
    }

    if( $("ul").hasClass('errorlist') && template == '/donate/')
    {
        address_fields.show();
    }    

    $("#id_address").live('focusout',function()
    {

        var intTest = /^\d{5}$/;
        $this = $(this);    
        var address = $this.val();      
        var split_addr = address.split(' ');
        var find_street = address.split(',');
        var street = find_street[0];
        var trim_street = street.split(' ');

        var clean_street = trim_street.splice(1,2).join(" ");       

        $('#id_address_number').val(split_addr[0]);

        // Find ZIP code in address
        for(i=0; i <= split_addr.length; i++)
        {           
            if(intTest.test(split_addr[i]))
            {
                $("#id_zip").val(split_addr[i]);
                zip = split_addr[i];
                //alert(zip);               
                break;
            }
        }

        //Find city
        $('#id_city').val($.trim(find_street[1]));


        // Find Street in address
        $("#id_address_street").val(clean_street);
        if(template == '/donate/')
        {   
            $(address_fields).show("slow");
            $('#id_pickup_id').closest('div').hide();
        }

        get_pickup_dates(zip,template)
    });


    $("#id_address").keypress(function (e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
          return false;
        }
        return true
    });

    $('div.field input, div.field select, div.field checkbox, div.field textarea').focus(function()
    {
        $this = $(this);        
        $this.closest('div').addClass('highlight');

    });

    $('div.field input, div.field select, div.field checkbox, div.field textarea').blur(function()
    {
        $this = $(this);

        $this.closest('div').removeClass('highlight');

    });

    if ($('#id_zip').val().length > 0)
    {
        zip = $('#id_zip').val()
        get_pickup_dates(zip,template)
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iFrames this might be a known (and now fixed) bug in jQuery/IE compatibility. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936